Vscode shows explorer files red after running build runner
I'm using the build runner package in my Flutter project. But whenever I ran the following command
dart run build_runner build

Some of the bloc state files turn red in the vscode file explorer. I have to open the state file and the error disappears. But doing this for many blocs is quite time consuming and frustrating. I tried the refresh button on the top of the file explorer window, but it does noting. What can I do to fix this?


The red file is probably and indication of uncommitted changes in Git.
Since build_runner generates new code, those files have been modified but haven't been committed
See also:

What does the Green and Red mark indicate in the Git file directory?


Those files don't have changes though.
